# Unable to reach to OS and TWRP after changing data type in TWRP on Asus smartphone

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, asus

I have an Asus smartphone. When I type `flash all aftk` to start the flashing process, it shows a black screen on my smartphone, on which a small message on the top-left corner is written to press the power button to shut down the device.

My phone is not showing in `fastboot devices`, only getting some question marks.

What should I do?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the phone model name.